# "Structure needs cleaning", apt-get / dpkg broken with error while processing package ca-certificates-java

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, java, 18.10

I can not install/pruge/reinstall or do anything using apt-get anymore. E.g. when I do:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I get:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/12.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 (--configure):
 unable to check existence of '/var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst': Structure needs cleaning
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ca-certificates-java:
 ca-certificates-java depends on openjdk-11-jre-headless | java8-runtime-headless; however:
  Package openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package java8-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 which provides java8-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 which provides java8-runtime-headless is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates-java (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64
 ca-certificates-java
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Reinstalling does not work either:

```
root@xubuntu:/var/cache/apt/archives# sudo apt-get install --reinstall oracle-java11-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gsfonts-x11 oracle-java11-set-default
Suggested packages:
  binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk | ttf-unfonts | ttf-unfonts-core ttf-kochi-gothic | ttf-sazanami-gothic
  ttf-kochi-mincho | ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  openjdk-11-jre-headless
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gsfonts-x11 oracle-java11-installer oracle-java11-set-default
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 1 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 45.4 kB/57.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 169 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 gsfonts-x11 all 0.26 [7140 B]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 oracle-java11-installer amd64 11.0.2-2~linuxuprising1 [35.1 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 oracle-java11-set-default amd64 11.0.2-2~linuxuprising1 [3116 B]
Fetched 45.4 kB in 0s (306 kB/s)               
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error processing package openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 (--remove):
 unable to check existence of '/var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst': Structure needs cleaning
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Doing:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-11-jre-headless
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge ca-certificate-java
```

does also not work and leads to similar issues while processing ca-certificates-java. Is there remedy for my situation?

**EDIT**

Affected device is casper-rw fs

```
sdd              28.7G                        
├─sdd1 ntfs      28.7G /isodevice             UUI
└─sdd4 ext2      12.2G                        casper-rw
```

Therefore `fsck` will not work.

Comment: That's right - broken packages must either be (re)installed properly before they can be removed...unless you use apt's --force flag. I generally recommend first trying to reinstall the package. If it fails, then read the output carefully to learn why.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, that reinstalling might work. 

That leads me again into a loop. Editing the question.

Comment: It doesn't look like a loop to me. The output seems to show a completely different problem now ("structure needs cleaning"). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/950050/how-to-solve-error-structure-needs-cleaning-on-root-file-system for ways to fix that problem.

Comment: Unfortunately "sudo touch /forcefsck" did not work for me as well.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "did not work for me." What, exactly, was the fsck result?

Comment: Using "sudo touch /forcefsck", did nothing on my system. Nothing returned on the console when I called the command as root and rebooting did not trigger any notable action.

Comment: Do you still get the "structure needs cleaning" error? If so, then you must still run `fsck`. There are many ways to do so. If not, then `fsck` did the job, and you can move on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94031/discussion-between-andreas-schwab-and-user535733).