# gnome-terminal and zenity will not install

Tags: gnome, dependencies, gcc, g++, zenity

I was tasked to update an nvidia jetson nano from Ubuntu 18 to 20.04. I followed this (https://qengineering.eu/install-ubuntu-20.04-on-jetson-nano.html) guide step by step, but while I was following it, some things popped up that were not on the guide and it eventually led me down to the rabbit hole I dug myself in. I'm not a linux user (not yet atleast) so I'm not experienced in navigating the terminal, or know what a lot of the commands and errors mean, I apologize if this is an easy fix.

I've gotten to the point where no other applications open up other than the terminal, not even settings.

When I got to the point in the guide where it said I had to install the gcc compiler using `sudo apt-get install gcc-8 g++-8`, I get this error:[after gcc install command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug64F.jpg)

It tells me of some dependencies that need to be installed; alot of g++-8 and gcc-8 dependencies (which are a problem), but the gnome-terminal and zenity dependencies are whats messing me up the most since I can't for the life of me get them to install, and when following guides online, alot of commands I do give back an error relating to these.

I tried to use `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and after continuing (choosing y in [Y/n]), it brings up this error: [after --fix-broken command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZptu.jpg)

I've tried to install the dependencies with `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal-data` and `sudo apt-get install zenity-common` but trying to install one requires the installation of the other. It's basically a never ending loop.
[loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNiKT.jpg)

The commands:

`sudo apt --fix-broken install zenity-common` (or the command: `sudo apt --fix-broken install zenity`)

`sudo apt --fix-broken install gnome-terminal-data` (or the command: `sudo apt --fix-broken install gnome-terminal`)

all bring up the same errors as before.

Is there a way this can be fixed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve error "Structure needs cleaning on root file system"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950050/how-to-solve-error-structure-needs-cleaning-on-root-file-system)

Comment: My apologies, I'm not sure how `sudo touch /forcefsck` works. I entered the command in the terminal but nothing happened after it asked me for my password. I saw that there is a `fsck <options> [filesystem]` command aswell, but I also don't know what the "options" and "filesystem" mean nor do I know how it can help me. (I'm really new to this)

Comment: The command creates `/forcefsck` file that tells the system check disks on next reboot.